# Scanf causes C program to crash

Tags: c, crash, scanf

This simple issue is causing my entire program to crash during the first input. If I remove the input, the program works fine but once I add scanf into the code and enter the input the program crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXEMPS 3


// stub program code
int main (void){
    char answer;

    do
    {

        printf("\n Do you have another(Y/N): ");
        scanf("%c", answer);
    }while(answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');

    getchar();
    printf("  Press any key ... ");
    return 0;
} // main
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` (or any other stream for which the last operation was input) is undefined by the Standard. If you're using Windows, the operation is well defined ... but if your code is ever going to be compiled on any other Operating System you will have an error that you could avoid right now. Do not `fflush(stdin)`!

Comment: Thank you for the information about fflush, my prof has us use it.

Comment: Hmm ... the equivalent Standard idiom is `int flushstdin(void) { int ch; while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF)) /* void */; return ch == EOF ? EOF : 0; }`. Talk to the prof and use it instead

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must pass the address of the variable to scanf:

```
 scanf("%c", &answer);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use "&answer".  And get rid of the extraneous "fflush()" commands...

Better, substitute "answer = getchar ()".