# error while executing the program

Tags: c, switch-statement, codeblocks, fflush, puts

i'am having some trouble in the execution of this code in Codeblocks. When i run the code it goes fine until the scanf line, after it an error occur and stop the code running.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    char lower, upper, option;

        puts("Type '.' to end the program.");
        printf("U-to upper\nL-to lower\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", option);
        switch(option){
            case 'u':
            case 'U':
                do{
                    fflush(stdin);
                    lower=getchar();
                    upper=toupper(lower);
                    putchar(upper);
                }while(lower!='.');
                break;
            case 'l':
            case 'L':
                do{
                    fflush(stdin);
                    upper=getchar();
                    lower=tolower(upper);
                    putchar(lower);
                }while(upper!='.');
                break;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c", option);` has no &

Comment: Turn your warning level up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanf causes c program to crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281054/scanf-causes-c-program-to-crash)

Comment: Thanks! I put '&' before option, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line `scanf("%c", option);` as follows,

```
scanf("%c", &option);
```

Now the program will work fine. **&** is required with **%c**.