# My program crashed and stopped working after reaching scanf() statement in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

I was just building a simple calculator in C using CodeBlocks. After building and running it it went smoothly till the scanf() statement. After i put in 2 numbers for my program to scan and hit enter the program crashed and sent a message "C.exe has stopped working."Please help. Here is the code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Calculator();

int main()
{
    Calculator();
    return 7;
}

int Calculator()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int operation;

    printf("Hello. I am a calculator.\nChoose any operation you want to carry out- \n 1.Addition \n 2.Subtraction \n 3.Multiplication \n 4.Division \n");
    scanf("%d", &operation);

    switch (operation)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("OK. You have chosen addition. \nEnter any 2 numbers to be added \n");
            scanf("%d", num1);
            scanf("%d", num2);
            printf("%d + %d is = %d. \n Thank you. ", num1, num2, num1 + num2);
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("OK. You have chosen subtraction. \nEnter any 2 numbers to be subtracted \n");
            scanf("%d", num1);
            scanf("%d", num2);
            printf("%d - %d is = %d. \n Thank you. ", num1, num2, num1 - num2);
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("OK. You have chosen multiplication. \nEnter any 2 numbers to be multiplied \n");
            scanf("%d", num1);
            scanf("%d", num2);
            printf("%d x %d is = %d. \n Thank you. ", num1, num2, num1 * num2);
            break;

        case 4:
            printf("OK. You have chosen division. \nEnter any 2 numbers to be divided \n");
            scanf("%d", num1);
            scanf("%d", num2);
            printf("%d ÷ %d is = %d. \n Thank you. ", num1, num2, num1 / num2);
            break;

        default:
            printf("\nHUH?\n\n");
            break;
    }
    return 20;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanf causes c program to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281054/scanf-causes-c-program-to-crash)

Comment: `return 7`? Just for fun? Try 42 ... :o

Comment: `scanf("%d", num1);` --> `scanf("%d", &num1);` in many places....

Comment: Also `return 20;` in `Calulator`? :o

Comment: Some reading: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: @purplepsycho thanks for referencing my doc ;) Unfortunately, it doesn't really cover this **very** basic stuff (like having to pass a pointer) ...

Comment: Thanks everyone. I just missed the "&" sign. Its working smoothly now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `scanf` calls inside the `switch` are wrong. You need `&`.

**Change**:

```
scanf("%d", num1);
scanf("%d", num2);
```

**to**:

```
scanf("%d", &num1);
scanf("%d", &num2);
```

I suggest you to check the return of `scanf`.

Try to understand this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Calculator( void );

int main( void )
{
    Calculator();
}

int Calculator( void )
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int operation;

    printf("Hello. I am a calculator.\nChoose any operation you want to carry out- \n 1.Addition \n 2.Subtraction \n 3.Multiplication \n 4.Division \n");
    if ( scanf("%d", &operation) != 1 ){
        printf( "Error scanf() ==>> on Operation" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    switch (operation)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("OK. You have chosen addition. \nEnter any 2 numbers to be added \n");
            if ( scanf("%d", &num1) != 1 ){
                printf( "Error scanf() ==>> switch - case 1 ==>> 1" );
                exit( 1 );
            }
            if ( scanf("%d", &num2) != 1 ){
                printf( "Error scanf() ==>> switch - case 1 ==>> 2" );
                exit( 1 );
            }
            printf("%d + %d is = %d. \n Thank you. ", num1, num2, num1 + num2);
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("OK. You have chosen subtraction. \nEnter any 2 numbers to be subtracted \n");
            if ( scanf("%d", &num1) != 1 ){
                printf( "Error scanf() ==>> switch - case 2 ==>> 1" );
                exit( 1 );
            }
            if ( scanf("%d", &num2) != 1 ){
                printf( "Error scanf() ==>> switch - case 2 ==>> 2" );
                exit( 1 );
            }
            printf("%d - %d is = %d. \n Thank you. ", num1, num2, num1 - num2);
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("OK. You have chosen multiplication. \nEnter any 2 numbers to be multiplied \n");
            if ( scanf("%d", &num1) != 1 ){
                printf( "Error scanf() ==>> switch - case 3 ==>> 1" );
                exit( 1 );
            }
            if ( scanf("%d", &num2) != 1 ){
                printf( "Error scanf() ==>> switch - case 3 ==>> 2" );
                exit( 1 );
            }
            printf("%d x %d is = %d. \n Thank you. ", num1, num2, num1 * num2);
            break;

        case 4:
            printf("OK. You have chosen division. \nEnter any 2 numbers to be divided \n");
            if ( scanf("%d", &num1) != 1 ){
                printf( "Error scanf() ==>> switch - case 4 ==>> 1" );
                exit( 1 );
            }
            if ( scanf("%d", &num2) != 1 ){
                printf( "Error scanf() ==>> switch - case 4 ==>> 2" );
                exit( 1 );
            }
            printf("%d ÷ %d is = %d. \n Thank you. ", num1, num2, num1 / num2);
            break;

        default:
            printf("\nHUH?\n\n");
            break;
    }
    return 20;
}
```

You should reconsider your `return` statements from `main` and `Calculator`

Answer (score 2):

You want to

```
scanf("%d", &num1);
scanf("%d", &num2);
```

at each instance.

Also, if you want to prevent other crashes, watch out for division by zero :)