# My program terminates as soon as I add the first input. I am not able to give my other inputs. What should I do?

Tags: c

**I am a person who just started learning to code in C two days ago.
I came across this problem:**
*"You have saved some amount to use as a down payment on a car. Before beginning your car shopping, you decide to write a program to help you find the monthly payment, given the purchase price, time period and monthly interest rate. The formula for payment is given as: payment=iP/(1-(1+i)^-i),
where P = purchase amount , i= monthly interest, n=total number of months.
Display the amount to be paid per month."*

**The following is the code I have made:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
    int P,i,n,mp;
    printf("Enter the required amount to be borrowed: ");
    scanf("%d",&P);
    printf("Enter the monthly interest: ");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("Enter the number of months you are willing to pay off this debt: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    mp=(i*P)/(1-pow((1+i),-n));
    printf("The amount you have to pay monthly is %d",mp);
}
```

When I run this code, I am able to enter the value of "P", after which the program terminates.

OUTPUT EXPECTED:
**Enter the required amount to be borrowed:**
*input*
**Enter the monthly interest:** 
*input*
**Enter the number of months you are willing to pay off this debt:**
*input*
**The amount you have to pay monthly is **
*calculated value*

OUTPUT I AM GETTING:
 **Enter the required amount to be borrowed:**
*input*
(Programs runs for a few seconds....ends)

Comment: Well, first follow-up question is "how does the expected and actual output differ?". Part of being a programmer is being precise about describing problems: "it doesn't work" is what laypeople say :}. Another aspect is breaking problems down into small independent parts, focusing on the relevant part(s)..

Comment: What was your input? What output do you expect? What did you get? While a potential answerer might infer that, it's good etiquette to make it easier for people to help you. `I am not getting the desired output` is very broad.

Comment: Really sorry for the lack of clarity. I am able to input only the value of "P" after which the program terminates.

Comment: @GSVP Enable *compiler warnings*. That should probably emit some useful information during compilation, and fixing those will avoid the crash. The program is running into a segmentation fault as scanf "tries to write to some random memory location".

Comment: use `scanf("%d",&P);`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Also, [searching for the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+scanf+crash) finds other code with the same error.. "[c] scanf crash" is just a distillation of the problem as explained.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanf causes c program to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281054/scanf-causes-c-program-to-crash)

Comment: I edited it to use scanf("%d",&P);  but it did not solve the problem

Comment: Are you getting the same error? Please edit your question with your current code with expected output

Comment: I have edited so as to include the whole picture. I am sorry about the earlier lack of clarity.