# Program crashes during line of scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to have the user input information and then verify the information is correct at a later point. However, when I reach the line to verify that the information is correct (a scanf line), the program hangs and crashes after about 2 seconds. I'm not sure what is happening, and nothing I have found works

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281054/scanf-causes-c-program-to-crash) but an ampersand didn't fix my problem.

Below is an excerpt of what I am doing

```
char check_values[2];
while (true) {

    printf("Is this information correct? y/n\n");
    // user information to verify is here
    scanf("%c", &check_values);  // this line isn't working for me

    if (strncmp(tolower(check_values), "y", 1) == 0) {
        // do one thing
    }
    else if (strncmp(tolower(check_values), "n", 1) == 0) {
        // do another thing
    }
    else {
        // do a third thing
    }
```

Comment: `strncmp(tolower(check_values), "y", 1)` is the "this line isn't working for me"

Comment: @chux I don't enter anything and the program still crashes, so I thought it would be the scanf line. Where is the string comparison incorrect?

Comment: People constantly use `scanf` in all sorts of inappropriate circumstances, and this is one of them. All this needs is a [`getchar()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) and `switch` on the result.

Comment: @user3121023 In the terminal if I wait on the `scanf` line, my program crashes. This makes me think it is not in the if statement

Comment: If it crashes, pop it open in a debugger and find out where.

Comment: If you don't see an error message for `tolower(check_values)` then fix your compiler settings as you are missing out on important diagnostics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are reading a single character, `y` or `n` you do not need to read in a string.

```
char check_values;
while (true) {

    printf("Is this information correct? y/n\n");
    // user information to verify is here
    scanf("%c", &check_values);  // read a single character.

    if (tolower(check_values) == 'y') {
        // do one thing
    }
    else if (tolower(check_values) == 'n') {
        // do another thing
    }
    else {
        // do a third thing
    }
}
```

Comment: When it stops working (as it will soon), you may need to change "%c" to " %c" (note the extra space).

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%c", &check_values)` 
**is not correct.** you need to pass a `char*` (pointer to `char`) to `scanf` not a `char**`(`&check_values` decays to: a pointer to a pointer of `char`).

Comment: `&check_values` is a pointer to array . `check_values` is an array, not a pointer.

Comment: yes its an array, but it decays to a pointer when passing to a function.

Comment: The `&` operator is not a function

Answer (score 0):

`check_values` is already interpreted as `char*`, so you need to pass `&check_values[0]` to `printf` or define `check_values` as `char check_values;`

---

edit:
`tolower` also expects a `char`, so you really should define `check_values` as `char check_values` or also pass `check_values[0]` to `tolower()`